# Opening 2 identical windows simultaneously from one set of code

Tags: user-interface, go, andlabs-ui

I am using following code to create and show a window with GUI components as label, entry and button:

```
// modified from: https://github.com/andlabs/ui/wiki/Getting-Started
package main
import ("github.com/andlabs/ui")
func makewinfn() {
    var name = ui.NewEntry()
    var button = ui.NewButton("Greet")
    var greeting = ui.NewLabel("")
    box := ui.NewVerticalBox()
    box.Append(ui.NewLabel("Enter your name:"), false)
    box.Append(name, false)
    box.Append(button, false)
    box.Append(greeting, false)
    mywindow := ui.NewWindow("MyTitle", 200, 100, false)
    mywindow.SetChild(box)
    button.OnClicked( func (*ui.Button) {greeting.SetText("Hello, " + name.Text() + "!") } )
    mywindow.OnClosing( func (*ui.Window) bool { ui.Quit(); return true } )
    mywindow.Show()
}
func main() {
    ui.Main(makewinfn)
    // HOW TO CREATE AND SHOW ANOTHER SUCH WINDOW HERE ?
    // ui.Main(makewinfn) // this opens window only after first is closed.
}
```

It works well, but as I mentioned in title and as commented in code above, how can I open two such windows simultaneously from main function?

Repeating `ui.Main(makewinfn)` in main function leads to second window opening only after first is closed.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems pretty clear from a glance at the code that one would expect the `ui.NewWindow` to be the call that creates a new window. Duplicating `ui.Main` I would assume is an error, I would expect it to be rather like `main()`, i.e. something to be called exactly once at startup.

Comment: I tried `func makewinfn() *ui.NewWindow{` so that it returns window object but error is: `*ui.NewWindow is not a type`

Comment: Right, it's a function, that creates and returns a new window object. Have you checked the documentation for this ui package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UI libraries usually the components or widgets you build the interface with have parents, and usually a single component may have at most one parent.

So if you want 2 windows, having the same components, you still have to create those components in 2 instances, because a component cannot be added to 2 different parents (in 2 different windows).

So simplest would be to move the component and window creation logic into a function, and call that twice from the function you pass to `ui.Main()`:

```
func createWindow() {
    var name = ui.NewEntry()
    var button = ui.NewButton("Greet")
    var greeting = ui.NewLabel("")
    box := ui.NewVerticalBox()
    box.Append(ui.NewLabel("Enter your name:"), false)
    box.Append(name, false)
    box.Append(button, false)
    box.Append(greeting, false)
    mywindow := ui.NewWindow("MyTitle", 200, 100, false)
    mywindow.SetChild(box)
    button.OnClicked( func (*ui.Button) {greeting.SetText("Hello, " + name.Text() + "!") } )
    mywindow.OnClosing( func (*ui.Window) bool { ui.Quit(); return true } )
    mywindow.Show()
}

func makewinfn() {
    createWindow()
    createWindow()
}
```

Using this `createWindow()` function of course is not a requirement, you could have a loop in `makewinfn()` with 2 iterations, each which could create a window.

The above example creates 2 identical windows, but they will be "independent". If you enter a text in one of them and click on its button, the result will only be seen in its containing / parent window. This is possible because each component has been created twice.

If you wan to customize the windows, you could pass a parameter to `createWindow()` so the window and its content could be customized / personalized based on its value. For example:

```
func createWindow(id string) {
    var name = ui.NewEntry()
    var button = ui.NewButton("Greet " + id)
    var greeting = ui.NewLabel("")
    box := ui.NewVerticalBox()
    box.Append(ui.NewLabel("Enter your name " + id + ":"), false)
    box.Append(name, false)
    box.Append(button, false)
    box.Append(greeting, false)
    mywindow := ui.NewWindow("MyTitle " + id, 200, 100, false)
    mywindow.SetChild(box)
    button.OnClicked( func (*ui.Button) {greeting.SetText("Hello, " + name.Text() + "!") } )
    mywindow.OnClosing( func (*ui.Window) bool { ui.Quit(); return true } )
    mywindow.Show()
}

func makewinfn() {
    createWindow("one")
    createWindow("two")
}
```

Comment: Great. Is it possible to create these two windows as objects so that I can access their name entry field from anywhere in program?

Comment: Also, currently closing one window closes both and ends the program. How to only close that window without ending program?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, you could store the windows in package level variables (you've seen how to do that in your previous question), and the `ui.Window` has a `Window.Title()` method for example to get its title. Since this time you have multiple windows, you could store them in multiple variables or in a slice.

Comment: And if you don't want to quit when a window is closed, you may set your own function how to handle window closing events, see the `Window.OnClosing()` method. Set a function in which you don't quit (or you decrement the visible window count, and if that reaches 0, then quit).

Comment: Great. Any idea why I got so many downvotes for this question!?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Go but assuming the GUI works like any other language I've used, in your makewinfn function you can simply create more windows by calling `ui.NewWindow()` again.

```
func makewinfn() {
    var name = ui.NewEntry()
    var button = ui.NewButton("Greet")
    var greeting = ui.NewLabel("")
    box := ui.NewVerticalBox()
    box.Append(ui.NewLabel("Enter your name:"), false)
    box.Append(name, false)
    box.Append(button, false)
    box.Append(greeting, false)
    mywindow := ui.NewWindow("MyTitle", 200, 100, false)
    mywindow.SetChild(box)
    button.OnClicked( func (*ui.Button) {greeting.SetText("Hello, " + name.Text() + "!") } )
    mywindow.OnClosing( func (*ui.Window) bool { ui.Quit(); return true } )
    mywindow.Show()
    myOtherWindow := ui.NewWindow("MyOtherTitle", 200, 100, false)
    myOtherWindow.Show()
}
```

Comment: The window does open but it is blank. I will have to add all components to `myOtherWindow` also and that is repetition of code. I want this function to return a customized window object which I can use as many times as needed. Problem is `Go` does not have classes hence how to get such an object.

Comment: Make that logic its own function and call it with the appropriate parameters.

Comment: It will be great if you alter your code to show this.